# List all services in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-services

There are some services in Windows (such as `http` and `USBStor`) which are not listed when you view Services, or when running the `Get-Service` cmdlet. What is the simplest way to list *all* services, even the hidden or unlisted ones?

For example, the `http` and `USBStor` services are not enumerated when listing services, but they can be accessed directly by name:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> Get-Service | Where-Object {"http","usbstor","spooler" -contains $_.Name}

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  Spooler            Print Spooler


PS C:\Windows\System32> Get-Service "http","usbstor","spooler"

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  http               HTTP Service
Running  spooler            Print Spooler
Stopped  usbstor            USB Mass Storage Driver
```

Comment: Try `ps` and see if it is different

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that this question is about Windows PowerShell.

Comment: Yes, `ps` is a powershell alias for `get-process`

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the most elegant way of getting all the services (hidden per say), but this will give you all the services along with ones these are dependent on.

```
Get-Service -RequiredServices | select -Unique DisplayName | ? {$_.DisplayName -like "Http*" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try 'Get-CimInstance'.

Such functions (Get-Service) delivered by Microsoft rely on and use CIM/Win32 classes.

(Get-Service only shows Windows services. 'HTTP' is a system driver.)

```
Get-CimInstance 'CIM_Service'
```